# How to avoid java script duplicate code in if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function with some stetemsnts inside:

```
 isFieldVisible(node: any, field: DocumentField): boolean {
        if (field.tag === 'ADDR_KOMU') {
            let field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
            return field.fieldvalue == 1;
        }

        if (field.tag === 'ADDR_SNAME') {
            let field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
            return field.fieldvalue == 1;
        }

        if (field.tag === 'ADDR_FNAME') {
            let field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
              return field.fieldvalue == 1 || field.fieldvalue == 2;
        }
}
```

How to improve it and avoid duplicates?

I have tried to use foreach with tuple as iteration value, but I can not return boolean from foreach

Comment: Does the second argument's value for **dfs_look** change for any case? If it does, then you can evaluate **field** once before all the conditional statements. Anyhow, a switch statement would definitely help since once a case is satisfied, you are returning anyhow.

Comment: Yes, could you share an sample?

Comment: Simply you can use javascript [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425813/how-to-improve-statement-in-functon/63426194#63426194) `OR(||)` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript `OR(||)` operator in `if` condition to avoid duplicate code.

```
isFieldVisible(node: any, field: DocumentField): boolean {   
       if (field.tag=== 'ADDR_KOMU' || field.tag=== 'ADDR_SNAME' || field.tag=== 'ADDR_FNAME' ) {
          let field= this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');            
          if(field.tag=== 'ADDR_FNAME'){
            return field.fieldvalue == 1 || field.fieldvalue == 2;
          }             
          return field.fieldvalue == 1;         
    }

}
```

Also, Check how to use [the logical "OR"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Logical_OR) operator, that is `||` in the `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement would definitely help save redundancy.

```
isFieldVisible(node: any, field: DocumentField): boolean {
        let field;
        
        switch(field.tag) {
            case 'ADDR_KOMU':
            case 'ADDR_SNAME':
                field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
                return (field.fieldvalue == 1);
            case 'ADDR_FNAME':
                field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
                return (field.fieldvalue == 1 || field.fieldvalue == 2);
            default: 
                //Do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
isFieldVisible(node: any, field: DocumentField): boolean {

 let field:{
      tag: "ADDR_KOMU" | "ADDR_SNAME" |"ADDR_FNAME",
      fieldvalue:boolean
 };

 switch (field.tag) {
      case 'ADDR_KOMU':
      case 'ADDR_SNAME':
           field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
           return (field.fieldvalue == 1);
      case 'ADDR_FNAME':
           field = this.dfs_look(node.children, 'ADDR_APPLICANTTYPE');
           return (field.fieldvalue == 1 || field.fieldvalue == 2);
      default:
      return
 }
```

}

Comment: Why you have two `field`?

Comment: i now that but i DocumentField the type of the  should be   tag: "ADDR_KOMU" | "ADDR_SNAME" |"ADDR_FNAME",
      fieldvalue:boolean